# Modbus Serial Port Data Reading in C#

Tags: c#, forms, serial-port, modbus

Hi I am trying to read the Serial Port Data. I used NModbus library for the modbus communication. Code works fine for read and write purpose. But sometimes i am having some unknown errors and i wanted to see the serial port activity. I tried using the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` but i am not getting anything from the port but still i am able to read the value of the holding registers. Here is my code. All i want to see the data packet being sent / received over the serial port.

```
namespace ModbusMaster
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form1_Load;


        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] baud = new int[] {4800,9600,19200,38400,57600,115200};
            int[] databit = new int[] { 7, 8 };
            int[] stpBits = new int[] { 1, 2 };
            string[] party = new string[] { "None", "Odd", "Even" };
            string[] Mode = new string[] { "ASCII", "RTU" };
            ModbusMode.DataSource = Mode;
            Baud_Rate.DataSource = baud;
            Data.DataSource = databit;
            Stop.DataSource = stpBits;
            Pari.DataSource = party;
            GetPortList();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ProtocolMode = ModbusMode.GetItemText(ModbusMode.SelectedItem);
            string portName = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select Serial Port!!!");
            }
            else
            {

                using ( SerialPort port = new SerialPort(portName))
                {
                    if (port != null && port.IsOpen)
                    {
                        port.Close();
                    }
                    // configure serial port
                    port.BaudRate = int.Parse(Baud_Rate.Text);
                    port.DataBits = int.Parse(Data.Text);
                    port.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), Pari.Text);
                    port.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), Stop.Text);

                    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                    port.Open();

                    // create modbus master

                    if (ProtocolMode == "RTU")
                    {
                        IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port);
                        int temp = ushort.Parse(StrtAdd.Text)- 1;
                        byte slaveId = byte.Parse(Slave.Text);
                        ushort startAddress = (ushort)(temp);
                        ushort points = ushort.Parse(regis.Text);
                        ushort[] holding_register = new ushort[] { };

                        holding_register = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, points);
                        string tempString = " ";
                        foreach (ushort value in holding_register)
                        {
                            tempString += value + " ";
                        }

                        val.Text = tempString;
                       // val.Text = Convert.ToString(holding_register[0] + " " + holding_register[1]);
                    }
                    if (ProtocolMode == "ASCII")
                    {
                        IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateAscii(port);
                        int temp = ushort.Parse(StrtAdd.Text)- 1;
                        byte slaveId = byte.Parse(Slave.Text);
                        ushort startAddress = (ushort)(temp);
                        ushort points = ushort.Parse(regis.Text);
                        ushort[] holding_register = new ushort[] { };

                        holding_register = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, points);
                        string tempString = " ";
                        foreach (ushort value in holding_register)
                        {
                            tempString += value + " ";
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        private void port_DataReceived(object sender,    SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            RcdPacket.Text = indata;

        }
        private void GetPortList()
        {

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string item in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                //store the each retrieved available prot names into the Listbox...
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }


        }

        private void WriteData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ProtocolMode = ModbusMode.GetItemText(ModbusMode.SelectedItem);
            string portName1 = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select Serial Port!!!");
            }

            else
            {
                using (SerialPort port1 = new SerialPort(portName1))
                {
                    if (port1 != null && port1.IsOpen)
                    {
                        port1.Close();
                    }
                    port1.BaudRate = int.Parse(Baud_Rate.Text);
                    port1.DataBits = int.Parse(Data.Text);
                    port1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), Pari.Text);
                    port1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), Stop.Text);




                    if (ProtocolMode == "RTU")
                    {
                        port1.Open();
                        IModbusSerialMaster master1 = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(port1);
                        int temp = ushort.Parse(WriteAdd.Text) - 1;

                        byte slaveId = byte.Parse(SlvIdd.Text);
                        ushort startAdd = (ushort)(temp);
                        ushort WrValue = ushort.Parse(WriteVal.Text);

                        master1.WriteSingleRegister(slaveId, startAdd, WrValue);
                    }
                    if (ProtocolMode == "ASCII")
                    {
                        port1.Open();
                        IModbusSerialMaster master1 = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateAscii(port1);
                        int temp = ushort.Parse(WriteAdd.Text) - 1;

                        byte slaveId = byte.Parse(SlvIdd.Text);
                        ushort startAdd = (ushort)(temp);
                        ushort WrValue = ushort.Parse(WriteVal.Text);

                        master1.WriteSingleRegister(slaveId, startAdd, WrValue);
                    }


                }

            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the traffic that flows i recommend using [Portmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) from Sysinternals. This also guaranties that what you see is actually what was received on the port

Comment: The thing is I want to display the traffic along with the decoded data from the incoming packet.