# .NET C# reading from serial after NModBus call

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus

I'm issuing a NModBus call (setting a register to 1) to a sensor that then triggers a transmission of binary data from the sensor via the serial port.

As long as I only read/write registers via NModBus, everything works just fine but when I want to read this returning byte flow, it just doesn't work.

I've tried a few different approaches:

- Using the same SerialPort
- Using two different SerialPort objects (on the same port of course) in case there were trailing buffers
- Reading "synchronously" immediately after the NModBus call
- Reading using SerialPortDataReceived
- Adding timeouts here and there (including adding waiting times on the sensor itself before starting transmission)
- Etc.

Depending on the approach, I may read 4 (four) bytes but I think they are the ModBus answer to the write register call. No way to retrieve the rest of the flow (a few hundred bytes). And *yes*, in case you were wondering, I *have* verified via a separate tool that such flow is indeed transmitted. :-P

I have exchanged information via serial port in other programs with no particular problems so I was wondering if the fact that I'm using NModBus *then* standard serial port operations *on the same port* is generating concerns?

The code - that is supposed to be pretty basic - looks like:

```
    using (SerialPort serialForModBus = new SerialPort(Port))
    {
       // Basic serial port settings
       Open(serialForModBus);
       // Create ModBus RTU master
       IModbusSerialMaster master = CreateMaster(serialForModBus);
       // Write register to trigger reading...
       master.WriteMultipleRegisters(SLAVE_ID, SensorModBusRegisters.COMMAND_SEND_LOGS, new ushort[] { (ushort)1 });
    }

    // Now read...
    using (SerialPort serialToReadLogs = new SerialPort(Port))
    {
       Open(serialToReadLogs);
       serialToReadLogs.ReadTimeout = 10000;
       // Externalize reading to separate class (that will also do the parsing..)
       SensorLogSerialReader logReader = new SensorLogSerialReader();
       serialToReadLogs.DataReceived += logReader.SerialPortDataReceived;
    }

// In SensorLogSerialReader 
public void SerialPortDataReceived(object senderSerialPort, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       SerialPort sender = (SerialPort)senderSerialPort;

       List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
       try
       {
          bool moreToRead = (sender.BytesToRead != 0);
          int cur;
          while (moreToRead)
          {
             cur = sender.ReadByte();
             bytes.Add((byte)cur);
             moreToRead = (sender.BytesToRead != 0);
          }

                    Done = true;
       }
       catch (...)
    }
```

Any idea? Am I missing something "evident"?

Thank you!

Note: I've seen an [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142004/modbus-serial-port-data-reading-in-c-sharp) that may be similar but remained unanswered

Comment: The author of the library isn't shy about it.  Quote: "NModbus only supports looping back one ushort value, this is a limitation of the "Best Effort" implementation of the RTU protocol".